# Sorting a List by ID

Tags: python, list, sorting

here is my list:

```
data_set = [['ID=j234hg\n'], ['Date=19 October 1969\n'], ['Title=Court Scene With Cardinal Richelieu\n'], ['ID=s4k5jk\n'], ['Date=8 December 1970\n'], ['Title=Crossing The Atlantic On A Tricycle\n'], ['ID=n4j6l3j\n'], ['Date=7 December 1972\n'], '[Title=Mr. Pither']]
```

I want to sort by ID:
here is my code:

```
for index,l in enumerate(data_set):
    if 'ID=' == l[0][:1]:
        data_set[index]="ID="+l[0][6:].sort()
print('Sort by ID')
print(data_set)
print()
```

the code runs but does not sort

Comment: You should carefully consider your data structures!

Comment: not everyone here is advanced or intermediate

Comment: can you update the data_set properly. You want to sort on the basis of ID but your data_set is a list containing lists as well as string

Comment: It is never too "advanced" to carefully consider the data structure you are using. Python provides built-in container data structures like lists, dicts, sets, tuples etc that are easy to use and have a rich, literal syntax. Any python programmer should be carefully considering if these will make their life easier. Your data is being represented by a *string* which makes you have to parse it every time to work with it. Probably, you want to work with a dictionary.

Comment: Also, why are some of your strings wrapped in a list (as the single element in that list), and others are not? That is *another* example of something which just makes your life harder without any discernible benefits. Please take this as constructive criticism. For the record, I did not downvote you.

Comment: I am not a python programmer, I am a beginner

Comment: @Mayank I have updated the data set and now have all lists

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga in order to truly understand object oriented programming you need to have a foundation which I do not have the fact I got this far using python only a month is a miracle. Saying things like Jeez is not helpful and condescending. No need to reply have a nice day.

Comment: @Supernova This has *nothing* to do with object oriented programming. I'm giving you the *sound advice* to carefully consider your container types. This is true in the object-oriented paradigm, in the functional paradigm, in *any* paradigm. If you don't want people to give you advice, then don't post a question on a question-and-answer site.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga no need to keep replying. Plenty of people give great advice on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that each row has fixed length of three items (ie:  ID, Date, Title), you can first regroup input and then sort.

```
rows = [ data_set[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(data_set), 3)]
print sum(sorted(rows, key = lambda r:r[0][0]), [])
```

output:

```
[['ID=j234hg\n'], ['Date=19 October 1969\n'], ['Title=Court Scene With Cardinal Richelieu\n'], ['ID=n4j6l3j\n'], ['Date=7 December 1972\n'], ['Title=Mr. Pither'], ['ID=s4k5jk\n'], ['Date=8 December 1970\n'], ['Title=Crossing The Atlantic On A Tricycle\n']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data_set looks something like this:

```
>>> data_set = [['ID=j234hg\n', 'Date=19 October 1969\n', 'Title=Court Scene With Cardinal Richelieu\n'], ['ID=s4k5jk\n', 'Date=8 December 1970\n', 'Title=Crossing The Atlantic On A Tricycle\n'], ['ID=n4j6l3j\n', 'Date=7 December 1972\n', 'Title=Mr. Pither']]
```

Try

```
>>> res = sorted(data_set, key=lambda x: x[0])
>>> res
[['ID=j234hg\n', 'Date=19 October 1969\n', 'Title=Court Scene With Cardinal Richelieu\n'], ['ID=n4j6l3j\n', 'Date=7 December
 1972\n', 'Title=Mr. Pither'], ['ID=s4k5jk\n', 'Date=8 December 1970\n', 'Title=Crossing The Atlantic On A Tricycle\n']]
```

Comment: the ouput puts all the dates first then IDs then Titles, let me try to tweak the code

Answer (score -1):

Use sets or dictionary to this kind of tasks. With list you can eventually print as first elements with word "ID", but without related data as title, date etc.